# How to delete Cookies from different path?

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

I want to delete a Cookie through Java Code which I have written like,

```java
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();  //request - HttpServletRequest  
for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {  
    if (cookies[i].getName().equals("cam_passport")) {  
        cookies[i].setMaxAge(0);     
        cookies[i].setValue("");  
        response.addCookie(cookies[i]);  
    }  
}
```

I am getting the list of cookies in the "cookies" object but not the required one "cam_passport".
What I have observed is, the PATH of this Cookie is different when I checked in Mozilla.
Where as, the list of Cookies which I am getting in my 'cookies' object have their path as "/".
And, for this "cam_passport" cookie, path is "/cognos10".

I need the above cookie to be deleted at one instance every time. How can I get the Cookies of different path like the above one?

Answer (score 1):

You need to send a redirect to that path, perhaps along with a request parameter. You can then in a servlet or filter which is mapped on exactly that path obtain the cookie and delete it, if necessary based on presence of the request parameter. Finally you can redirect back to the original URL, if necessary based on a request parameter.

In the future, use `cookie.setPath("/")` during creating the cookie if you need the cookie to be available throughout the entire web application.